# Multiple Instances of GZServer and GZWeb

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am newbie to gazebo and gzweb. What I am doing is to connect multiple users to different sessions of gzweb on my computer. Once a user logged in with their account, system will login to their account on terminal and create a gazebo platform with gzweb. I can run multiple gzweb instances on different ports with different hostnames but, all of them connects to one instance of gzserver. I tried exporting GAZEBO_MASTER_URI variable to different hostnames and ports according to gzweb's host and port. gzserver starts multiple times while users are different but never connects to gzweb or vice versa.
Any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17183/multiple-instances-of-gzserver-and-gzweb/) by [alicanuzunn](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3794/alicanuzunn/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-09-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

gzweb's websocket server's address is currently hardcoded to 7681 so you'll probably need to manually change it to a differnt port for each gzweb you run. Here's the port number on [server side](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gzweb/src/501c03e86181c72311dc2b70582ed6018d604ee5/gzbridge/ws_server.js?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#ws_server.js-37), and you'll need to update the [client side](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gzweb/src/501c03e86181c72311dc2b70582ed6018d604ee5/gz3d/src/gziface.js?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#gziface.js-32) too.

---

Originally posted by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) with karma: 1018 on 2017-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alicanuzunn](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3794/alicanuzunn/) on 2017-09-08**:
thank you, I just made it according to your answer, in addition, I changed the gz3d.js's port too.